# Node JS + Express won't run, DEBUG=appname ./bin/www

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I'm trying to get a node/express server running on a mac, and this command isn't running

```
DEBUG=ExpressApp ./bin/www
```

This is the error that gets thrown out:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jaysen/Desktop/ExpressApp/app.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

**UPDATE**

After re-running npm install, I just get a blank line.

Comment: have you run `npm install` first to install all your packages? The error suggests that `express` is being required but not installed.

Comment: i've just done that, and now whenever I run the same command I just get a blank new line, any ideas?

Comment: Well without seeing any code, I assume that is correct because you probably aren't doing anything inside your app to prevent it from exiting. To confirm that it's working correctly try spitting out a `console.log` message.

Comment: Ah yes it does work, silly me.Shouldn't it say the port?

Comment: No, it's not obliged to say anything :) if you see examples of it spitting out any sort of logging it's usually handled by the tools / debuggers attached to the process. Node itself won't output anything unless you tell it to.